Can a person patent something invented by AI?
I know that AI has been barred from becoming patent holders. Can a person patent an invention conceived by AI?

I am not a lawyer so this is not legal advice. I am an inventor. Inventors use automation tools all the time to help with the invention process. Computerized tools such as CFD, FEA, etc. are as commonly used as a pencil. If you use an AI tool and it generates something that you recognize as novel and useful, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to file a patent on it. Please recognize that generative AIs don't really think in the purest sense. It isn't really much different from using a protein folding software to predict useful drug compounds. The software generates a number of candidates and the chemist tries them and discovers one or more works. You're not even obligated to disclose the tools used in your discovery of the invention.
Be advised that based on the answer posted by bhuff36, my answer is incomplete. There needs to be some contribution to the inventive process by a human within each claim. This is consistent with the current situation where someone can only be added as an inventor if the contributed to the actual invention rather than just worked on the project. In any case, I would suggest the other answer by bhuff36 is the more correct one.

https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2024/02/13/2024-02623/inventorship-guidance-for-ai-assisted-inventions states that "inventorship is improper in any patent or patent application that includes a claim in which at least one natural person did not significantly contribute to the claimed invention" (i.e., to the exclusion of claims where only an AI significantly contributed). Sometimes there is significant contribution when setting up an AI to search for candidate solutions, but in some cases there may not be. While disclosing tools is not obligatory, there is still the oath/declaration.

@bhuff36 As I said, I am not a lawyer. You should feel encouraged to post your own answer. Setting up the search with an AI is a contribution and even more so understanding the potential novelty of the response along with the inevitable development that would be needed. My reference to using protein folding software is particularly relevant. I've used software from a company called "Invention Machine" that purports to provide novel solutions to engineering problems. I never found it very compelling.

the same document I linked states further, and somewhat in contrary to your comment, that "a natural person who merely recognizes and appreciates the output of an AI system as an invention, particularly when the properties and utility of the output are apparent to those of ordinary skill, is not necessarily an inventor". the guidance document I linked from USPTO on this subject is not even that long. A good answer would be informed by that document but explain it in simpler terms; the correct answer would be "maybe"; but unfortunately I don't have the time for that at the moment.

@bhuff36 I edited my answer to refer to you additional comments and answer. I'd like to point out that the quote "properties and utility of the output are apparent to those of ordinary skill" sure sounds like the output of the AI would be considered obvious.

The USPTO has recently issued a guidance document on this subject; it is available here.
The long and short if it is, every valid claim must have some part of human inventorship to it. When interacting with an AI, human inventiveness may be exhibited in formulating the query or in properly interpreting the results or applying further inventive steps/transformations to the output of the AI.
In cases where the human has only applied efforts that were routine, the AI has "invented" all by itself and no patent can be granted to the human (or their employer/assignee).
Somewhat paradoxically, inventions that might be discoverable by an AI remain patentable to human inventors who choose not interact with AIs (of course, provided there was no prior publication by someone who used the AI on the same problem). This is because the rules regarding AI affect only inventorship; there has been no change to the rules regarding obviousness, which is still judged from the perspective of a person of ordinary skill (as opposed to, say, such a person supplemented with access to a contemporanous AI).
